# H2 database usage of external library like apache.commons

Tags: h2, apache-commons

I was trying to use H2 Database. I want to call methods in Apache Commons Library i.e. commons-maths3.jar.

H2.bat looks as follows:

```
@java -cp "commons-math3.jar;h2.jar" org.h2.tools.Console %*
```

But when accessing the library method with the following:

```
CREATE ALIAS sd for "org.apache.commons.math3.stat.descriptive.moment.StandardDeviation";
```

I am getting 90086 error.

```
Class "org.apache.commons.math3.stat.descriptive.moment" not found; SQL statement: create alias sd for "org.apache.commons.math3.stat.descriptive.moment.StandardDeviation" [90086-193] 90086/90086
```

Also, please suggest me how to know that a library is accessible to H2 something like DESCRIBE StandardDeviation.

Is there anything I am missing here.

Comment: Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quote from [the H2 manual](http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#create_alias):

> The method name must be the full qualified class **and method name**, and may optionally include the parameter classes as in java.lang.Integer.parseInt(java.lang.String, int). The class and the method must both be public, and the method **must be static**. The class must be available in the classpath of the database engine.

<sup>(Emphasis mine)</sup>

So you need to specify a static *method* for the alias, not a class name.

But [`StandardDeviation`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.6.1/index.html) has no static methods. You need to write a (static) wrapper function (in Java) yourself if you want to use that.